# split string consecutively by the length of other string in php?

Tags: php

**How to split the first text variable below according to the length of second variable**

```
$text = "hey how are you";
$text1 = "how are you";
$length = strlen($text);
$length1 = strlen($text1);
```

Comment: What do you mean what are you expecting as output??

Comment: i want to return every index where the same data/element is found in given text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_split](http://php.net/str_split):

```
$text = "hey how are you";
$text1 = "how are you";
$length = strlen($text);
$length1 = strlen($text1);
$parts = str_split($text, $length1); 
// Array([0] => hey how are [1] =>  you)
```